# Can StackLayout in Xamarin.Forms use "weight" like Linearlayout of Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'd like use BoxView to present timelines, and each color of the lines represents a kind of task.
I have used Grid to do this. However, you know, minute is a small unit so that there are hundreds of rows in one page. That leads to a performance problem.
With Xamarin.Android, I can use Linearlayout, set height "0dp" and set weight attribute a suitable value to do this.
Well, can StackLayout do so? If not, which other layout should I use.

[effect drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWjeY.jpg)

Comment: StackLayout is simply used to render multiple views sequentially. It does not calculate the size of its children, but will resize itself to contain its children unless instructed to also expand to fill its parent. You would need to calculate and set the height of each BoxView to achieve the effect you're describing.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. For my design, the height of view is always same to the device's height. So,  how do I calculate the number of DIPs needed? And how to deal when device's height changed such as orientation changed.

Comment: You can always reference the view's [computed height](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.height?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_VisualElement_Height) at runtime which will allow you to distribute a percentage of the total height between your BoxViews.